# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS sudo apt-get update Errors

Tags: 20.04

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                              
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:3 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                
Err:4 http://ubuntutym.u-toyama.ac.jp/ubuntu focal InRelease                                       
  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
Err:5 http://ubuntutym.u-toyama.ac.jp/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
Err:6 http://ubuntutym.u-toyama.ac.jp/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
Err:7 http://ubuntutym.u-toyama.ac.jp/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
Reading package lists... Done                             
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntutym.u-toyama.ac.jp/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 160.26.2.187 80]
```

Comment: Read your output: Apt is not broken. Apt is merely passing along connection errors. You have a networking problem.

Comment: Try "sudo apt update" and then "sudo apt upgrade" in terminal

Comment: I tried "sudo apt update" and then "sudo apt upgrade" in the terminal,but the same output